# How to get the image address behind the flash shell in this website?

Tags: web, flash-player

THe following image is linked through a flash player. Any way to dig out the real address?
web page: http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/?l=shop,pdp,ctr-inline/cid-1/pid-361818/pgid-361817

useful image link http://images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/PDP_P/Nike-Out-Train-the-Game-Mens-T-Shirt-404128_703_A.png

Comment: OT: Yugh, can't believe a brand like Nike would create an entire website in flash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I hate Nike's site.)

A page more apt for a screen reader, http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/ .

Pages from there don't use Flash, so pictures you can save directly.

Comment: r u sure it's a correct address? It's still all flash for me.

Comment: Then maybe it was setting a cookie (on my end) telling it not to use Flash.  Try this link first, & see if subsequent links forgo Flash: http://store.nike.com/redirect_html.jsp?country=US&l=shop,pdp,ctr-inline/cid-1/pid-406329&lang_locale=en_US .

Comment: It worked! Safari can view it smoothly while in Chrome the website displays distorted. Even though I am expecting of a more technical solution as the flash image quality is much better than the non flash one. THX!

Comment: By the way, how did u come across this non flash site? I tried to disable flash plugin in my browser and then the page doesn't display at all.

Comment: I disabled "Styles" in SeaMonkey (View | Use Style -> None), & on doing that at the top of the page it displayed "Click for a different version of this web site containing similar content optimized for screen readers" (a link similar to the link in the above comment).